# How to clone radio buttons in jQuery with modified checked status?

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have cloned radio-list,while i checked radio button and click on 'Add More' button then new cloned radio-list is added but added radio-list the radio buttons are not modified/checked by the user,the status of radio buttons are fixed.
Here is my html code

```
<div class="Box">
   <div class="form-group">
        <label ><span>Note Type:</span></label>
         <div class="radio-list">                
                <label><input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="Subjective"> Subjective</label>
                <label><input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="Objective" > Objective</label>
         </div>
         <div class="abc">
            <button type="button" id="num">Add More</button>
         </div>
   </div>  
<div>
```

hers is js code.

```
   $("#num").click(function () {
       var p = $('.form-group').length;
       var cloned = $(".form-group:first").clone(true)
                .find('input:radio').attr('name', 'optionsRadios' + ++p).end()
                .appendTo('.Box');
    });
```

Comment: can you provide your javascript code

Comment: Ah that's an easy one, you need to do some jQuery ;) Post what you tried.

Comment: maybe you clone it without change the cloned radio button name?

Comment: When cloning, the attributes are cloned, i.e. the initial state. The properties are not cloned, i.e. what changes when the user check/uncheck the radios. Post the code that clones the buttons, the HTML is irrelevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- your code should be wrapped with `document.ready`.
- you should change `name` of `input`s in cloned `div` to another unique one (to make separate group of radiobuttons).
- you have `</span>` without `<span>`.
- I moved `<div class="abc">` out of `<div class="form-group">` to prevent buttons from copying.

It should be something like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/41akkt0a/1/).

```
var cloneId = 0;

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#num").click(function()
    {
        var clone = $(".form-group:first").clone(true);
        clone.find("input").prop("name", "optionsRadios" + cloneId);
        cloneId++;
        clone.appendTo(".row");
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried it in my project still same thing happens,any other reason for getting this issue

Comment: @HariKrishna Do you use any libraries to style radio buttons? It's hard to say what is wrong when provided code works in fiddle. Maybe you should provide the link to your site...

Comment: yes, it is caused due to style the radio buttons, now removed and tried,the code works fine.                                                      Thank you.